# Two different Sobolev exponents

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I'm looking at two different Sobolev inequalities on Wikipedia and I can't reconcile the differences between their corresponding Sobolev exponents. The first is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#k_%3C_n/p

Let's take $n$ large, $k = 1$, and $p = 2$, so we are in the $k < n/p$ case. Then the Sobolev dimension on the left hand side satisfies
$$ \frac{1}{q} = \frac{1}{p} - \frac{k}{n} $$
which implies $q = 2n/(n-2)$.

The second is the Gagliardo-Nirenberg interpolation formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality):
$$ ||D^ju||_p \leq C||D^mu||_r^\theta||u||_q^{1-\theta} $$
for $j, m, n, q, r, \theta$ determining $p$. If I take the same parameters as before: $j = 0$, $m = 1$, $q = r = 2$ and $\theta = 1/2$, in which case $p = 2n/(n-1)$.

So the problem is that the Sobolev dimension appears different; I can use Young's inequality to get
$$ ||D^mu||_r^\theta||u||_q^{1-\theta} = ||Du||_2^{1/2}||u||_2^{1/2} \leq \frac{1}{2}(||Du||_2 + ||u||_2) $$
which is equivalent to the Sobolev norm $||u||_W^{1,2}$. So I apparently have two different $L^p$ spaces on the left hand side and I can't see why. I also can't use rescaling to get the correct exponent since I have two terms on the right hand side and scaling $||Du||_2$ for instance small makes $||u||_2$ large. The only thing I've noticed is that the first Sobolev inequality is done on a bounded domain but there is a mention that it can be unbounded as well, and I don't know what I'm missing/why these differ.

Comment: Yes, if you take $\theta = 1/2$, you get something intermediate. You should take $\theta = 1$ to get Sobolev. This picture might let you better understanding these inequalities https://laurent-lafleche.perso.math.cnrs.fr/images/GagNir.svg

Comment: Thanks - I see $\theta = 1$ gets me the same Sobolev exponent $2n/(n-2)$, but I don't see how the two inequalities differ. In the first, the right hand side is the $W^{k,p}$ norm $(||Du||_2^2 + ||u||_2^2)^{1/2}$ which is equivalent to $||Du||_2 + ||u||_2$? Or is the fact I use Young's inequality significant?

Comment: Yes, Young's inequality is indeed significant ... just look at the other extreme point $\theta = 0$ ;)

Comment: Ah ok, I think I see! And $2n/(n-2) > 2n/(n-1)$ as well, so the interpolation gives a weaker exponent. Thanks!